# Отправка сообщения в поле чата PHP

Tags: php, html, chat

Хочу написать общий чат на PHP.
После того как юзер залогинился он переходит на страницу чата, где вводит свой никнейм и может писать сообщения в общий чат.
Как можно настроить отправку сообщения в поле `area`?
Вот код:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo trim($_SESSION['email-e']).", "."Вы авторизованы <br />";
?>
<script>
var name = prompt('Input your nickname','');
document.write('Your nickname is, ' + name);
</script>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    .area {border: 1px solid black;width: 200px;height: 250px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="area"></div>
<input type="text" name="name"><br />
<input type="button" name="button" value="Отправить">
</body>
</html>
<?php
if($_POST['button']) {
    $message = '';
}
?>
```

Comment: Обновлять чат через ajax

Comment: Запустить сокет